# Returning a property map from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Here is my code:

```
function currentCursPos(){
$(document).mousemove(function(e){ var pos= {"x":e.pageX,"y":e.pageY}; return pos });
}
function clrpckrTopPos(){
    //var cursorPos={};
    var cursorPos=currentCursPos();
    if(cursorPos.y<$("#colorpickerDiv").height()){return cursorPos.y+$("#colorpickerDiv").height()}
    if(cursorPos.y>$("#colorpickerDiv").height()){return cursorPos.y}//colorpickerDiv2 and colorpickerDiv have same height
}
```

I get the error that:

> 'cursorPos is undefined'

Any ideas how to achieve the task of returning a property map from a function. What mistake I am making?

Comment: What is the overall intent of these functions?  Are you trying to know where the mouse is after a certain event?  Or are you trying have a element react to the mouse position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this using global variables:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){ x = e.pageX; y=e.pageY; });
function clrpckrTopPos(){
    if(y<$("#colorpickerDiv").height()){return y+$("#colorpickerDiv").height()}
    if(y>$("#colorpickerDiv").height()){return y}//colorpickerDiv2 and colorpickerDiv have same height
}
```

Comment: I am using this code with the above code . Here clrpckrTopPos() doesnt seem to work : $("#colorpickerDiv").css({"left":($(this).offset().left)+40,"top":clrpckrTopPos()});

Comment: Try using an alert to check the value returned by `clrpckrTopPos()` in case it's returning something strange

Answer (score 2):

`currentCursPos` doesn't return anything.
Returning from a `mousemove` handler inside a function doesn't make the outer function itself return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the current cursor position in a global variable on `mouseMove`:

```
var pos;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) { pos = { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY }; });

function clrpckrTopPos(){
    if (pos.y < $("#colorpickerDiv").height())
        return pos.y + $("#colorpickerDiv").height();

    if (pos.y > $("#colorpickerDiv").height())
        return pos.y;
}
```

Comment: You should replace cursorPos by pos. Also x and y should be enclosed between inverted commas.

Comment: oops, thanks on the `cursorPos` catch! But quotes are required only for JSON. Pure JavaScript object identifiers don't need to be enclosed in quotes.